# The R^2 score I get from GridSearchCV is very different from the one I get from cross_val_score, why? (sklearn, python)

Tags: python, statistics, scikit-learn, regression

I'm using GridSearchCV to pick a regressor. Once it's fitted, I pull out the chosen regressor with

```
predictor = GridSearchCV(Pipeline(...), params={...},
                         cv=10, scoring='r2')
predictor.fit(X, y)
estimator = predictor.get_params()['estimator']
```

and then I run `cross_val_score` with

```
cross_val_score(estimator, X, y,
                cv=10, scoring='r2')
```

but the R^2 I get is consistently about 5 percentage points lower than `predictor.best_score_`. Why?

Comment: It would be useful to have a full account of which estimator you are using. Even better would be a fully copy+pasteable script with random data. If my answer doesn't help, this may be estimator specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `predictor.best_estimator_` as the estimator in `cross_val_score`. This is the one with the best parameters. The way you choose it, you are probably obtaining the initial estimator with default parameters. You could check by putting the latter in `cross_val_score` as well and comparing results.